# Python script that checks "McAfee Security Status"

Tags: python, mcafee

I'm trying to create a script that return the status of McAfee,
all I have now is this window:

[image]

My question is: How can I access .. with my script to copy my results to the clipboard? Is it saved in a text file somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

As you have guessed, the safest way to attempt this would be to automate the click of the `Copy to Clipboard` button. It might also be possible to extract the text directly from the list box above but this would get too complicated.

To do this you need to send a Windows message to the McAfee window to simulate clicking on the button using the `Win32` [SendMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. In order to work out the function parameters, you will need to use a tool such as [Microsoft's Spy++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460756.aspx). This is used to expose various values associated with a window that you will need to access it.

First you will need to obtain the Window handle using a function such as [FindWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Spy++ will give you the window title or window class you will need to call this function.

You will then need to obtain the ID of the `Copy to Clipboard` button. With this you could now use the `SendMessage` function.

Both of these functions can be called using Python's `ctypes` library, for example, for `Notepad` you could call it as follows:

```
import ctypes

notepad_handle = ctypes.windll.user32.FindWindowW(None, "Untitled - Notepad")
```

As an alternative, does McAfee not have a command line utility to report the same information? This would be easier to use.

Comment: On the [Command line](https://kc.mcafee.com/resources/sites/MCAFEE/content/live/PRODUCT_DOCUMENTATION/20000/PD20010/en_US/e5200wpg.pdf) I couldn't find anything that can help, it's possible to use your method but it's the hardest one, and as you said .. there should be another option from McAfee .

Answer (score -1):

check some part of this path:
The default location is C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\McAfee\DesktopProtection\UpdateLog.txt

if not works just look: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\McAfee\